# Joining mongodb collection based on condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two collections in MongoDB and want to join the two collections based on some condition.

I want to join 'order' and 'order-status' table to get all orders assigned to '123' with status 'ready'

**orders**

```
{
 "_id":"1",
 "name": "Fridge",
 "assignee": "123"
},
{
 "_id":"2",
 "name": "TV",
 "assignee": "567"
},
{
 "_id":"3",
 "name": "Music system",
 "assignee": "123"
}
```

**order-status**

```
{
 "_id":"1",
 "status": "ready",
 "orderId": "1"
},
{
 "_id":"2",
 "status": "cancelled",
 "orderId": "2"
},
{
 "_id":"3",
 "status": "cancelled",
 "orderId": "3"
}
```

**assignee**

```
{
 "_id":"123",
 "name": "Jak"
}
{
 "_id":"567",
 "name": "Mac"
}
```

I want to join 'order' and 'order-status' table to get all orders assigned to '123' with status 'ready'

**Expecting a final result as**

```
[
{
 "_id":"1",
 "name": "Fridge",
 "assignee": "123",
 "status": {
  "_id":"1",
 "status": "ready",
 "orderId": "1"
 }
}
]
```

Tried following but how to check order status in another table with lookup

```
const resultObject = orders.aggregate([
  { $match : {assignee: Objectid('123')} },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'user-status',
      localField: 'assignee',
      foreignField : '_id',
      as : 'assignee'
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$assignee'
  }
]);
```

Comment: can you give sample data for assignee?

Comment: @SuleymanSah I have a doubt, do I need to put assignee in order-status table to get database proper reference?
 ie "assignee": "123"

Comment: can you give sample data so that we can check?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Updated assignee collection

Comment: Hmm, actually there is no need to join assignee,  I sent an answer, can you check please?

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer to get the exact result you wanted, can you check please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use match to filter by `"assignee": "123"`, then you need to lookup order-status, match `"orderStatus.status": "ready"`.

```
const resultObject = orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      assignee: "123"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "order-status",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "orderId",
      as: "statuses"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "statuses.status": "ready"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: "_id",
      name: "$name",
      assignee: "$assignee",
      status: {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$statuses", 0]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

This will give result like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "assignee": "123",
    "name": "Fridge",
    "status": {
      "_id": "1",
      "orderId": "1",
      "status": "ready"
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1yPdAFe321p)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following pipeline:

```
const resultObject = orders.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            assignee: Objectid('123')
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:
            {
                from: "order-status",
                let: {order_id: "$_id"},
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match:
                            {
                                $expr:
                                    {
                                        $and:
                                            [
                                                {$eq: ["$orderId", "$$order_id"]},
                                                {$eq: ["$status", "ready"]}
                                            ]
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                ],
                as: "stock"
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$stock"
    },
    // now we get the assignee info.
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'user-status',
            localField: 'assignee',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'assignee'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$assignee'
    },
    //finaly create the required structure.
    {
        $project: {
            name: "$assignee.name",
            assignee: "$assignee._id",
            status: "$stock.0"
        }
    }
]);
```